# how to get the post id in the option tag

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, options

```
$term_id .= $_POST['main_brand_id'];
        $term = get_term( $term_id, 'state' );
        $slug = $term->slug;
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'post_type' =>'dealers','taxonomy'=>'state', 'term' => $slug );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
            echo '<option>';
                $options .= '<option value="'.$post->id.'">';
                $options .=  the_title();
            echo '</option>';
        endforeach;
```

I have to pass the **post id** to get the output as below

```
<option value="24">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="29">Bangalore</option>
<option value="44">Delhi</option>
```

This piece of code is not working........

```
$options .= '<option value="'.$post->id.'">';
```

This is the output im getting

```
<option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option>Bangalore</option>
<option>Delhi</option>
```

can anyone help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$post->id` needs to be `$post->ID`

You can also use `get_the_ID()`

Since your calling `setup_postdata()` you need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your foreach loop.

You also need to echo the value of $options somewhere.

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
                $options .= '<option>';
                $options .= '<option value="'.$post->id.'">';
                $options .=  get_the_title();
                $options .= '</option>';
                    echo $options;
        endforeach;
```

Comment: Chris_O thanks for the response, tried it, but didn't worked.

Comment: Can you add `var_dump( $post );` somewhere in your foreach loop and report back what the output is?

Comment: Also where are you echoing the value of $options?  the_title prints to the screen so that could be your problem.

Comment: actually i have to echo like this-----> echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Select Post</option>'.$options; but its not working,..... yes chris u r right, the post title prints in the drop down and when i check in the page source i dont get the post id in the value attribute....

Answer (score 0):

i did like this chris.........

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<option value="'.$post->id.'">';
            $options .=  the_title();
        echo '</option>';
    endforeach;
```

and its working, Thank you soo much Chris for ur awesome help............